# В stackoverflow не отображается в коментариях возможность поставить лайк (он же принятие ответа)?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, принятые-ответы

Не могу понять почему у меня нет возможности проставлять/выбирать ответ  из комментариев.

Вот как у меня:

> [image: Вот так отображается у меня!]

А вот так я ожидаю что должно быть:

> [image: А вот так у другого пользователя, есть возможность голосовать за коментарий]

Comment: Сергей а как посмотреть это  ограничение в 10 пунктов (где именно на сайте  об этом есть инфо)?

Comment: @OlegPpogiJ, скорее 15 [Если вы прочитали вопрос, ответ или **комментарий** и он показался вам особенно полезным, голосуйте за него!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

Comment: Потому что рейтинг ещё не набрал.

Comment: А это магическое число которое мне надо набрать где написано что бы о нем можно было почитать?- я пока не обнаружил текста с описанием  дайте ссылку плиз.

Comment: @OlegPpogiJ хм, раньше вроде было упоминание в [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up), но сейчас не вижу этого в тексте 

Comment: @OlegPpogiJ? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges - тут список привилегий, подозреваю, что надо 50, но может быть 15. Не очень уверен.

Comment: то ли я ничего не понял, то ли автор вопроса спрашивает, почему не может проголосовать за **собственный** комментарий. ответ, вроде бы, вполне очевиден, но, видимо, требует какой-то формальной формулировки.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin это просто скрин [другого юзера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/997256/%d0%92%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-js-%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b#comment1692049_997262)

Comment: получил ответ  в разделе с вопросом -------"Какие существуют ограничения на голосования, изменение мнения и отмену своего голоса?"